# FutureBuilder strange behavior

Tags: flutter

FutureBuilder has a strange behavior that I don't understand.
When I'm writing a method that **returns a FutureBuilder** like this:

```
  FutureBuilder _buildScreenFromFuture() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirestoreHistory.documentsAmountDescending(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
```

I get the following message

```
{
    "resource": "/home/adam/Flutter/Hisab/lib/Screens/history_screen.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": "invalid_cast_function_expr",
    "severity": 8,
----> "message": "The function expression type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>)' isn't of type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)'. This means its parameter or return type doesn't match what is expected. Consider changing parameter type(s) or the returned type(s).",
      "source": "dart",
...
}**strong text**
```

But when I change the return type of the method to Widget, there's no error.

Even though it's an easily resolved issue, I'm just curious to know why this happens.
Also, I find specifying the return type of a method (instead of Widget) to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _buildScreenFromFuture() {
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: FirestoreHistory.documentsAmountDescending(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
```

Without `<QuerySnapshot>` it thinks it is `dynamic`